# Understand starstar-wildcard

Tags: vimgrep

I read `:h starstar-wildcard`, but I cannot understand some cases.

(In the following examples, I am using the command `:vimgrep pattern file` where "pattern" is contained in the concerned files.)

1- If I have the files `foo.txt` and `dir/foo.txt` and execute `:vimgrep pattern **.txt`, only the first file is found. Why?

2- If I have a file `foo.txt` and execute `:vimgrep pattern **/*.txt`, the pattern is found in the file. I would have expected only files with a `/` in its name would match (so only .txt files in subdirectories). Why is the `/` ignored?

3- `**` seems to only match files, not directories. Is that right?

I think I am misunderstanding how the `**` wildcard really works.